# Run Lizmap stack with docker-compose

Tags: qgis, server, lizmap

I tried installing lizmap with docker compose on an ubuntu machine. In the desktop version I can log in to localhost.
I'm trying to connect with 0.0.0.0 so as to simulate connecting from outside the machine (like a server)

I changed the pointing to `LIZMAP_PORT=${LIZMAP_PORT:-"127.0.0.1:8090"}`
by entering 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1

When I connect from the outside, I can see the login form, in a minimal version without graphics. I log in and see the lizmap page but as soon as I click it gives me 500 errors

How can I solve it?
I would also like to have a secure server setup

```
COPY_COMPOSE_FILE=0
LIZMAP_VERSION_TAG=${LIZMAP_VERSION_TAG:-"3.5"}
QGIS_VERSION_TAG=${QGIS_VERSION_TAG:-"3.22"}
POSTGIS_VERSION=${POSTGIS_VERSION:-"13-3"}
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-"postgres"}
POSTGRES_LIZMAP_DB=${POSTGRES_LIZMAP_DB:-"lizmap"}
POSTGRES_LIZMAP_USER=${POSTGRES_LIZMAP_USER:-"lizmap"}
POSTGRES_LIZMAP_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_LIZMAP_PASSWORD:-"lizmap1234!"}
QGIS_MAP_WORKERS=${QGIS_MAP_WORKERS:-"1"}
WPS_NUM_WORKERS=${WPS_NUM_WORKERS:-"1"}
LIZMAP_PORT=${LIZMAP_PORT:-"127.0.0.1:8090"}
OWS_PORT=${OWS_PORT:-"127.0.0.1:8091"}
WPS_PORT=${WPS_PORT:-"127.0.0.1:8092"}
POSTGIS_PORT=${POSTGIS_PORT:-"127.0.0.1:5432"}
POSTGIS_ALIAS=${POSTGIS_ALIAS:-"db.lizmap"}
```

Comment: For an external reference, the question has also been posted on GitHub : https://github.com/3liz/lizmap-docker-compose/issues/57

Comment: I tried, without touching anything, to work via iptable.
So all requests from IPs are routed to the IP address of the nginx:alpine container.
what do you think can it go?

Answer (score 0):

When installing Lizmap, open the "*default.env*" file before the "*./configure configure*" command. Change the line 14   as   *LIZMAP_PORT=0.0.0.0:8090*
Then go on installation. Maybe ".env" file inside the lizmap folder has the same effect but i didn't try.